# How can I have both qwerty and azerty keyboards on same computer same time?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, qwerty

I have both an azerty and a qwerty keyboards on my computer.

The azerty keyboard (FRA) is a real keyboard.
The qwerty keyboard (ENG) is a magnetic track card reader recognized as a keyboard.

My windows 8 (but could be any windows) is configured with both FRA and ENG regional settings and I can switch easily between the two configuration using ALT+SHIFT.

I am wondering if there is any way to force the keyboard disposition (for one or the other) at a hardware level, perhaps by using a specific driver file or a specific software ? The main objective is to be able to use both inputs without having to change the keyboard layout in windows.

Many thanks for your help and/or your ideas :)

Comment: How are the keyboards connected to the computer through the USB? In my experience I have been able to connect two USB keyboards to a single computer and both keyboards allowed input.

Comment: I need to check with two real keyboards !

Comment: I guess you need a driver which takes care of input from the keyboard and pass it to your OS in its own layout, despite the preferred layout set in OS settings. Or, a script which will make the switch for you, automatically. As you said you can easily switch between those layouts via two keys. I would walk on that easy way.

Answer (score 1):

The card reader could be setup as an OPOS card reader. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPOS
Many manufacturers have OPOS drivers along with how-to setup instructions.

Use a google search to look for your exact model and manufacture, Unless it is something that belongs in a museum, there should be resources.